# Pcamera stream audio and video to web browser

Tags: raspberry-pi, rtsp, pyaudio, ip-camera, picamera

I am trying to make a PTZ IP camera with a Raspberry Pi Zero. I am also using an adafruit motor controller bonnet that utilizes python code to command the motors. I found a nice tutorial for a , python, picamera based program on Random Nerd Tutorials for this project
This program works amazingly except for the fact that it doesnt stream audio.I am using The adafruit I2S MEMS microphone for audio input. It has been tested on its own and I get really clear recordings. My question is, is it possible to allow for audio streaming to a web-browser that is in sync with the video I am streaming in this project. And if so, how would I go about doing it? The only reference to audio I found in the Picamera Github repository is something to do with MMAL

***Microphone Info***

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sndrpii2scard [snd_rpi_i2s_card], device 0: simple-card_codec_link snd-s
oc-dummy-dai-0 [simple-card-card_codec_link snd-soc-dummy-dai-0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**Tutorial page:** https://randomnerdtutorials.com/video-streaming-with-raspberry-pi-camera/
**Github link:** https://github.com/RuiSantosdotme/Random-Nerd-Tutorials/blob/master/Projects/rpi_camera_surveillance_system.py
**Picamera documents:** https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes2.html
**Picamera MMAL link:** https://github.com/waveform80/picamera/blob/master/picamera/mmal.py

*Project Code*
`

```
import io
import picamera
import logging
import socketserver
from threading import Condition
from http import server

PAGE="""\
<html>
<head>
<title>Raspberry Pi - Surveillance Camera</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>Raspberry Pi - Surveillance Camera</h1></center>
<center><img src="stream.mjpg" width="640" height="480"></center>
</body>
</html>
"""

class StreamingOutput(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = None
        self.buffer = io.BytesIO()
        self.condition = Condition()

    def write(self, buf):
        if buf.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):
            # New frame, copy the existing buffer's content and notify all
            # clients it's available
            self.buffer.truncate()
            with self.condition:
                self.frame = self.buffer.getvalue()
                self.condition.notify_all()
            self.buffer.seek(0)
        return self.buffer.write(buf)

class StreamingHandler(server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.send_response(301)
            self.send_header('Location', '/index.html')
            self.end_headers()
        elif self.path == '/index.html':
            content = PAGE.encode('utf-8')
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            self.send_header('Content-Length', len(content))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(content)
        elif self.path == '/stream.mjpg':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Age', 0)
            self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private')
            self.send_header('Pragma', 'no-cache')
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=FRAME')
            self.end_headers()
            try:
                while True:
                    with output.condition:
                        output.condition.wait()
                        frame = output.frame
                    self.wfile.write(b'--FRAME\r\n')
                    self.send_header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
                    self.send_header('Content-Length', len(frame))
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write(frame)
                    self.wfile.write(b'\r\n')
            except Exception as e:
                logging.warning(
                    'Removed streaming client %s: %s',
                    self.client_address, str(e))
        else:
            self.send_error(404)
            self.end_headers()

class StreamingServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, server.HTTPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True
    daemon_threads = True

with picamera.PiCamera(resolution='640x480', framerate=24) as camera:
    output = StreamingOutput()
    #Uncomment the next line to change your Pi's Camera rotation (in degrees)
    #camera.rotation = 90
    camera.start_recording(output, format='mjpeg')
    try:
        address = ('', 8000)
        server = StreamingServer(address, StreamingHandler)
        server.serve_forever()
    finally:
        camera.stop_recording()
```

`